# Is it possible to float two links with font-awesome icons to the right in a dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

In a standard twitter bootstrap navbar dropdown, I would like to have three links, the usual text link and then two font awesome icons (also links) that are floated to the right.

Currently, if more than one link is placed within the `li` element it drops to a new line.

This is what I would like.

[image: Desirable]

http://www.bootply.com/F35vbPUBAu

Answer (score 1):

Just alter the markup a little, and add some CSS. See [**this updated demo**](http://www.bootply.com/vW5v5NcWHL). Basically, you need to remove some padding and cleared floats, and add floats to the anchors...

For this html (in the dropdown):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="pull-left fix-pad-right">Course One</a>
        <a href="#" class="pull-right fix-pad-left"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="pull-right fix-pad-mid"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="pull-left fix-pad-right">Course One</a>
        <a href="#" class="pull-right fix-pad-left"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="pull-right fix-pad-mid"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="pull-left fix-pad-right">Course One</a>
        <a href="#" class="pull-right fix-pad-left"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="pull-right fix-pad-mid"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This added CSS:

```
.fix-pad-left, .fix-pad-right, .fix-pad-mid {
    clear: none !important;
}

.fix-pad-left {
    padding-left: 3px !important;
}

.fix-pad-right {
    padding-right: 3px !important;
}

.fix-pad-mid {
    padding: 3px 3px !important;
}
```

Makes it look like this:

[image: screenshot]

HTH :)

Comment: Thank you, I might be asking too much but is there a way to keep the ```li``` hover highlight?

Comment: absolutely--by default the hover effect is on the anchors, change it to the li and you're good to go..lemme see here...ok look at [**this bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/bBFw2g5ULj)

Comment: thank you, that's great, just one last thing, with a long anchor tag, the icons drop to a new line, any way to prevent this? If I truncate the text, the icon still drops down.

Comment: Also, can this be extended to add more icons, say four or five?

Comment: Sure [take a look here](http://www.bootply.com/pnT8a4XBDe). Note that I added an inline style to set the width of the drop down menu `<ul>` element.You could do this with a class or whatever, but you'll need to set the width to accommodate your longest line of text/icons. Otherwise they'll wrap.

Comment: Can the width of the ul be dynamic or would that as you say cause the icons to drop to a new line?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is by surrounding all of the content in each li for the list you want to edit in a div tag, then style that tag. I was able to make a quick change in your code that partially worked.

```
<li> <div> <a href="#">Course One</a> <a href="#"><span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></span></a><a href="#"><span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></span></a> </div> </li>
```

This pulls everything onto the same line, then you just have to tweak the css, padding and everything to get the desired result you want.

[image: An example of just adding div tags to your code without extra styling]

This works by making the li contain a div which is a unique container on it's own that can hold more elements. The li element otherwise makes some assumptions about the content within.

To override the style, just put the bootstrap style from their files into the following or something similar.

```
li div {
   background-color: red;
}
```

This sets the background color/style for everything contained in the div and should work great. Picture proof below.

[image]

Comment: I had done that too by surrounding with a <div class="row"> tag but as your answer shows that removes all styling.

Comment: It removes all styling since bootstrap makes the assumption that each element to be styled is a child of the li element and not the div element. So, just copy the style to work for a nested div in a li element and it should all work.

Comment: Check my updated answer with how to just override the style. Shouldn't take much if you just inspect the element of the bootstrap style and copy it to the nested div styling.